# JQuery Tablesorter sort datetime

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I'm using Jquery tablesorter and have a datetime that needs to be sorted.

Format:- Mon May 02 2016 12:31:00

Currently, Im using the "time" sorter but that does not work.

```
2:{
   sorter: 'time'
  }
```

Is there a existing sorter that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Umm, I guessing you only wanted to sort by time? If you meant sort by date AND time, then use the "shortDate" parser ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/1577/)).

If you're using my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), this should work without any extra code ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/bbxxomhx/6/)):

```
$(function() {
    $('table').tablesorter({
      headers: {
        0: {
          sorter: 'time'
        }
      }
    });
});
```

If you're using the original tablesorter, then include this parser ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/1576/)):

```
$(function() {
    var ts = $.tablesorter,
    dateReplace = /(\S)([AP]M)$/i,
    // match 24 hour time & 12 hours time + am/pm - see http://regexr.com/3c3tk
    timeTest = /^([1-9]|1[0-2]):([0-5]\d)(\s[AP]M)$|^((?:[01]\d|[2][0-4]):[0-5]\d)$/i,
    timeMatch = /([1-9]|1[0-2]):([0-5]\d)(\s[AP]M)|((?:[01]\d|[2][0-4]):[0-5]\d)/i;

  ts.addParser({
    id: 'time2',
    is: function(str) {
      return timeTest.test(str);
    },
    format: function(str, table) {
      // isolate time... ignore month, day and year
      var temp,
        timePart = (str || '').match(timeMatch),
        orig = new Date(str),
        // no time component? default to 00:00 by leaving it out, but only if
        // str is defined
        time = str && (timePart !== null ? timePart[0] : '00:00 AM'),
        date = time ? new Date('2000/01/01 ' + time.replace(dateReplace, '$1 $2')) : time;
      if (date instanceof Date && isFinite(date)) {
        temp = orig instanceof Date && isFinite(orig) ? orig.getTime() : 0;
        // if original string was a valid date, add it to the decimal so the column
        // sorts in some kind of order; luckily new Date() ignores the decimals
       return temp ? parseFloat(date.getTime() + '.' + orig.getTime()) : date.getTime();
      }
      return str;
    },
    type: 'numeric'
  });

  $('table').tablesorter({
    headers: {
      0: {
        sorter: 'time2'
      }
    }
  });
});
```